# What is the pattern for composite views in backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

For example, I have a view attached to the body.  All other views are attached to elements with in the body.

This leads me to believe I should be using a multiple views with in a view pattern.

But I'm not sure if I should, or if I should, how to do it.

Here is my top level view

```
// login shortcut "view"
var  UserTryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    Name: 'UserTry',
    el: window,
    keys: {},
    events: {
        "keyup"                   : "keyup",
        "keydown"                 : "keydown"
    },
    keydown: function (e) {
        console.log('keydown detected');
        var self = this;
        this.keys[e.keyCode] = null;
        $A.testKeys(this.keys, '1684', function () {
            self.render();
        });
    },
    keyup: function (e) {
        delete this.keys[e.keyCode];
    },
    render: function () {
        new FavoritesView({el: $A.el('#mm')});
         //new FeedView({el: $A.el('#at_view')});
        // new AccountView();
        // Storage.setObj(packet.server.smalls);
        Page.flip('main');
    }
});
var user_try_view = new UserTryView();
```

Comment: your thinking in the right direction, in JS you learn patterns, in other languages you learn features.

Comment: if you dont mind checkout marionettejs - there is a very good approach in use.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you needs marionette.js or you should invent your own approach

You can create LayoutView and define regions inside this view. Then you can render other views inside specific region.

Read more:
https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layoutview.md